# How to fix this OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((unsigned)i < (unsigned)cn) in cv::Vec<unsigned char,3>::operator (), file

Tags: c++

I'm setting up an random aria for an object from an image at image processing for an exercise in my desktop application for school. Where do I need to put the value of my colour(there are the 3 colour of canals) magenta?

`

```
void first(Mat img, Vec3b magenta)
{
    int H = 255;
    int W = 255;
    int n = 255;
    int aria=0;

    for (int r = 0; r < H - 1; r++){
        for (int c = 0; c < W - 1; c++){
            int pixel = img.at<uchar>(r, c);
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                if (pixel = magenta(i))
                    aria++;


            }

        }
    }
    printf("Aria obiectului este:%d \n", aria);
}

void MyCallBackFunc1(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param)
{
    //More examples: http://opencvexamples.blogspot.com/2014/01/detect-mouse-clicks-and-moves-on-image.html
    Mat* src = (Mat*)param;
//  int aria;
    if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        printf("Pos(x,y): %d,%d  Color(RGB): %d,%d,%d\n",
            x, y,


            (int)(*src).at<Vec3b>(y, x)[2],
            (int)(*src).at<Vec3b>(y, x)[1],
            (int)(*src).at<Vec3b>(y, x)[0]);
        Vec3b magenta;
        magenta[0] = (int)(*src).at<Vec3b>(y, x)[0];
        magenta[1] = (int)(*src).at<Vec3b>(y, x)[1];
        magenta[2] = (int)(*src).at<Vec3b>(y, x)[2];
        Mat img = ((Mat*)param)->clone();
        first(img, magenta);

    }
}


void testMouseClick1()
{
    Mat src;
    // Read image from file 
    char fname[MAX_PATH];
    while (openFileDlg(fname))
    {
        src = imread(fname);
        //Create a window
        namedWindow("Window", 1);

        //set the callback function for any mouse event
        setMouseCallback("Window", MyCallBackFunc1, &src);

        //show the image

        imshow("Window", src);

        // Wait until user press some key
        waitKey(0);
    }
}
```

My function is called First and it calculates the aria of an object image given by the parameter Mat img. I'm usingmy function in TheCallBackFunc1 where I call the TestMouseClick1 which prints the position of the mouse coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I discover that there is a problem with '=' and I put '==' and the problem still persist.

First-chance exception at 0x76CB18A2 in OpenCVApplication.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x00B2E484.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.